# after clicked button , array become null?

Tags: c#

```
void GetTestQuestion()                               
{// this function will randomly choose question from question array and store into new   array named testQuestion
i = 0;
while (i < max)
{
Random();
if (question[num, 0] != string.Empty)
{
testQuestion[i, 0] = question[num, 0].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 1] = question[num, 1].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 2] = question[num, 2].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 3] = question[num, 3].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 4] = question[num, 4].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 5] = question[num, 5].ToString();
testQuestion[i, 6] = question[num, 6].ToString();
i++;
}            

}
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// this button is to show the question into listbox...
for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
ListBox1.Items.Add(testQuestion[i, 1].ToString());
}
}
```

first, i will randomly pick a question from Question Array and store into testQuestion array.. but, after i clicked on the button, my testQestion array become null value... whats go wrong??

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: How is this question related to C? Isnt this C#

Answer (score 0):

What are you comparing the if statement to because the code inside the if statement is what it implements. So it's looking for this: question[num, 0] outside the statement to compare != string.Empty.